# Why is HashMap#get() in a foreach loop returning null?

Tags: groovy

For `groovy -v`: `Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.6.0_26 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux`:

```
def map = new HashMap()
def keyVariable = "a"
def valueVariable = "b"
map.put("${keyVariable}", valueVariable)

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    println map.get(key)
}
```

This prints `null`. Could someone explain why Groovy finds the key, but can't find the corresponding value by the same key?

Comment: This doesn't print `null` according to my test...

Comment: It worked for me. What's your setup? Mine is `Groovy Version: 2.1.5 JVM: 1.8.0-ea Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
`

Comment: I suspect in coming up with a simple example to post to StackOverflow, you've removed the thing that caused the problem ;-)

Comment: Sorry all; I've fixed the code so it reproduces what I actually encountered.

Comment: Groovy Templated Strings make for really bad map keys as equality doesn't really work...  A workaround is `map.put("${keyVariable}".toString(), valueVariable)`

Comment: I'm a Java programmer and complete Groovy novice, so I was a bit confused by the multiple ways of referring to Groovy Strings. I went with `map.put(keyVariable, valueVariable)` in the end.

Comment: @william.berg You can just do: `map[ keyVariable ] = valueVariable` to achieve the same thing with less typing :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question doesn't print `null` for me (Groovy 2.1.6)

#### After the edit, the issue is that Groovy templated Strings make really bad map keys

More idiomatic Groovy would be:

```
def map = [:]
def keyVariable = "a"
def valueVariable = "b"
map[ keyVariable ] = valueVariable

map.each { key, value ->
    println value
}

// Or

map.keySet().each { key ->
    println map[ key ]
}
```

Comment: @william.berg Ahh yes, Groovy templated Strings make really bad map keys :-(